# re.finditer (R or K but not RP or KP) in one line

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I want to have index of `P` or `K` but not `PR` or `PK` in substring. Now I can do two-line code but it is slower than using `for` loop with `if`. I want very fast one with `re.finditer`, is it possible ?

```
proseq = "NSDSECPLSHDGYCLHDGVCMYIEALDKYACNCVVGYIGERCQYRDLKWWELRP"
xxx = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('(R|K)', proseq)]
yyy = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('(RP|KP)', proseq)]
print list(set(xxx)^set(yyy))
OUT> [40, 27, 44, 47]
```

The `for` loop that is faster than mine (and it is sorted),

```
proseq = "NSDSECPLSHDGYCLHDGVCMYIEALDKYACNCVVGYIGERCQYRDLKWWELPR"
cut_sites=[]
for i in range(0,len(proseq)):
    if proseq[i]=='K' and proseq[i+1]!='P':
        cut_sites.append(i)
    elif proseq[i]=='R' and proseq[i+1]!='P':
        cut_sites.append(i)
OUT> [27, 40, 44, 47]
```

Other fast ways are very welcomed.

Comment: Use `P(?![RK])|(?<!P)K` regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex `(R|K)([^P]|$)`. This reads freely as "R or K, followed by a character which isn't P (`[^P]`), or the end of the string (`$`)".

Thid regex would practically give you the results without the need for another check.